# Doctrine 2 Dynamic Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to make a dynamic search query with doctrine. And it's not working

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$city = 'new york';
$minprice = 500;
$maxprice = 1000;

$testquery = "SELECT p FROM AcmeTestBundle:Car p WHERE p.city = :city";
$testparam = array('city' => $city,);

if ($minprice != '') {
    if ($maxprice != '') {
        $testquery .= " and p.price BETWEEN :minprice AND :maxprice";
        $testparam .= array(
            'minprice' => $minprice,
            'maxprice' => $maxprice,
            );
    }
}

$testquery .= " ORDER BY p.price ASC";

$query = $em->createQuery($testquery)->setParameters($testparam);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: array $testparam...

I think I would concatenate array with "+" operator not "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, the approach you have taken is fine. However, I can see at least two things wrong.

1) Doctrine doesn't support BETWEEN, so you'll need something like:

```
    $testquery .= " and p.price >= :minprice AND p.price <= :maxprice";
```

2) The .= is a string operator only, you cant use it with arrays. So you'll have to do something like this (you could do an array_merge but that seems like overkill):

```
    $testParam['minPrice'] = $minPrice;
    $testParam['maxPrice'] = $maxPrice;
```

Comment: thanks it's working now! is this method also sql-injection-proof?

Comment: Yes, as long as the parameters are set via setParameters() it doesn't matter how you build the parameter array. Could you up-vote and accept the answer if it fixed your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In php, you cannot use `.=` with arrays. Instead, do

```
$testparam['minprice'] = $minprice;
$testparam['maxprice'] = $maxprice;
```